# Cognos 8 API Integration with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, report, integration, cognos

I wanted to integrate cognos 8 and fetch the reports in excel/xml/csv format from cognos server. I don't have much knowledge about cognos, so can you provide me some pointers to start this process.

Right now, i'm accessing the Cognos 8 server using IBM's sandbox server, is it possible to use this server as a testing interface? can you also provide me some documentation/link to get more information about cognos 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking the easy way and fetching reports (or part of reports) through the mashup services (introduced in 8.4.1). Here is the "Get started" article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1001cognosmashup/index.html?ca=drs-

You can find more info regarding this topic in SDK documentation.