# How to access Cognos Rest API

Tags: cognos

Is it possible to get the status of reports running on cognos server via REST API. Does cognos has built in rest api?? I have reports running on my cognos server. How to check this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the SDK, part of it is [Cognos Mashup Services](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/cognos-mashup-service/), which supports REST or SOAP to integrate reports with other applications.  I've never heard of trying to use it to monitor anything, but you can certainly use the SDK to check report status.  Is there some reason you can't just use the native UI?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR you can check what is going on (running and completed reports/jobs) on your cognos system via Audit package with at least basic logging set up. No need for SDK there.
Have a look at this document: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21643478&aid=1
It will guide you how to enable and configure auditing.

Then, you can set up reports using Audit package and use cognos mashup service to retrieve that.
[Cognos mashup services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111783/cognos-8-api-integration-with-asp-net/2364112#2364112) works, even without SDK installed (worked for me on 8.4).